# Using Php PDO Insert statement

Tags: php, database, pdo, insert

Someone told me that when you are working with PDO, you cannot use "INSERT INTO .... SET" to insert data into database, because it will not work on databases other than MySQL. I'm not sure what exactly he means, maybe he means I should use the other method of inserting like,

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)
```

I tried searching on the internet for this, but I couldn't find anything. Please let me know about this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `INSERT INTO ... SET` syntax is not part of the ANSI SQL standard and therefore is not supported as widely across different RDBMS implementations.  If you are designing your application such that it is tightly coupled to MySQL, using this syntax would be OK.  If you are trying to design such that your application is not tightly coupled with the RDBMS implementation, then you should use the more standard `INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES (values)` syntax.

Comment: Thank you. Your answers and those below were really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)` statement instead of the `INSERT INTO table SET column1=?` statement, because that's the correct syntax for SQL based database languages. Although [MySQL accepts it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html), others may not.

Answer (score 0):

Positional parameters in PHP PDO is just fine. The other option is named parameters. If I remember correctly from what I've seen in the PDO C code, it is PHP and not the DBM that does the replacements.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

As stated in **[this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)** the only metioned difference, b/n mysql driver and others  is stated below. Suppose this is the a simple, query:

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');
$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $row_count.' rows selected';
```

Now, let's read how the documentation states how/why that query can return count of `affected_rows` only when the mysql driver

> **NOTE**: Though the documentation says this method is only for returning
>   affected rows from `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` queries, with the PDO_MYSQL
>   driver (and this driver only) you can get the row count for `SELECT`
>   queries. Keep this in mind when writing code for multiple databases.
>
> This is because MySQL's protocol is one of the very few that give this
>   information to the client for `SELECT` statements. Most other database
>   vendors don't bother divulging this information to the client as it
>   would incur more overhead in their implementations.

So, there is that little difference, as far as I know.

Comment: Good to know this as well. Thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question asked?

Comment: It is relevant to the question